# Sum of row elements between colMin and colMax, with different colMin and colMax for each row - Octave / Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, sum, octave

I have matrix

```
p=[1 2 3 4; 
   5 6 7 8; 
  10 20 30 50];
```

I'd like to compute the sum of the elements of each row that are between column iMin and iMax, with iMin and iMax being different for each row

e.g for

```
iMin = [3 2 1];
iMax = [4 4 3];
```

the result is

```
[7 21 60]
```

Is there an easy Octave / Matlab way to do this without loops ?

Comment: I think a loop may be the most readable solution.

Comment: Yes, but I'm looking for a solution without loop for speed's sake, as actual computations will take place on much larger matrices...

Comment: In more recent versions of Matlab, the loops will also be faster. Anyway, where do you get the iMin and iMax from? Is that from indices you pull from another array of the same size as `p`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using logical indexing, following a similar approach to my answer to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10258448/matrix-creation-octave-matlab-loopless-solution-request).

Assuming that `iMin` and `iMax` have the same number of entries as the number of rows in `p` you can horizonally tile the column indices for `p` i.e. `[1:size(p,2)]` and compare this to vertical tilings of `iMin` and `iMax` to generate a logical index into `p` for the entries that satisfy your criterion so:

```
c_min=repmat(iMin',1,size(p,2))
c_max=repmat(iMax',1,size(p,2))
c_ind=repmat([1:size(p,2)],size(p,1),1)
result=sum(p.*(c_ind>=c_min & c_ind<=c_max),2)
```

Giving:

```
result =

   7
  21
  60
```

No loops :-)

Comment: Thanks ! On Octave, relative speed seems to depend on the shape of matrix p :

P matrix of size 100 000 x 200 :
% Your method (repmat) = 0.34 sec
% Jonas's method 1 (loop) = 2.20 sec
% Jonas's method 2 (arrayfun) = 4.92 sec.

P matrix of size 200 x 100 000 :
% Your method (repmat) = 0.68 sec
% Jonas's method 1 (loop) = 0.41 sec
% Jonas's method 2 (arrayfun) = 1.412 sec

Your method seems consistently quick, the loop method is also fast but gets penalised when the number of rows gets huge. Arrayfun is slower.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm a little late, but here's my contribution:

1. A one-liner with [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

   ```
   sum((p.*bsxfun(@le,iMin(:),1:size(p,2)).*bsxfun(@ge,iMax(:),1:size(p,2))).')
   ```
2. A solution with [`linear indexing`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html?s_tid=doc_12b#f1-85511):

   ```
   aux = [zeros(1,size(p,1)); cumsum(p.')];
   rowjumps = 0:size(p,2)+1:numel(p);
   result = aux(iMax+1+rowjumps) - aux(iMin+rowjumps);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure that

```
[nRows,nCols]=size(p);
result = zeros(nRows,1);
for iRow = 1:nRow
   result(iRow) = sum(p(iRow,iMin(iRow):iMax(iRow));
end
```

is the fastest solution, at least on more recent versions of Matlab.

To perform the summation in one go, you need to create an array of ones and zeros to mask `p`, i.e.

```
[nRows,nCols] = size(p);
idxCells = arrayfun(@(x,y)...
    [false(1, x-1), true(1,y-x+1), false(1,nCols-y)], iMin, iMax,...
    'UniformOutput',false);
result = sum( p .* cell2mat(idxCells), 2)
```

Comment: Thanks! On a recent Octave, the for loop is the fastest for small nRows, but not the fastest when nRows increases (see comment to rroowwllaanndd's answer above). No idea if a recent Matlab version would change this conclusion...